# How to avoid 'Login Only' rejection from Google Adsense program?

Tags: adsense

I am currently trying to setup an Adsense account for a client so they can put ads on their website. This is a new site and it has been rejected by Google because they say it is a 'Login Only' website. Whilst the site does have the ability to register/login (and this is encouraged) all pages are accessible publically without registering but if you are logged in then they become more personalised (eg on the search results page it lists your distance to each users and related info like this if you're logged in). There are no pages on the site that can only be viewed while logged in. I understand GoogleBot can't tell this itself but what is the accepted way of getting around this?

I have read elsewhere recommendations to completely remove the login section from the site, resubmit it, wait for approval and then add the login options again, however this seems like Google may think we're trying to hoodwink them (which we're not) and i don't want to get his account blocked for doing anything bad. We can obviously add login information within the site authentication section of Adsense which would presumbly solve the problem and allow GoogleBot to see behind the login but this can't be done until the account is activated which seems rather contradictory. I wonder if I add the site to my Adsense account, add authentication information so it can crawl it and then resubmit will this work? Alternatively we could set him up Adsense on a completely different site, get the account approved then add the authentication information but this seems like an extremely long winded way of setting it up.

I would greatly appreciate information as to how this should be dealt with in a proper and correct manner so as to not cause problems in the future.

Thanks very much,

Dave

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google advertising policies, not programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or would be a better place to ask.